# Ubuntu Server Hanged on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, putty

i had Ubuntu 16.04 installed on AWS EC2, i was able to connect to it using Putty in the past, but before couple of days, i was unable to connect to the server using the Putty.

when i checked the instance from AWS console management i found out that it's CPU utilization was 100% for a long time and not going down, i have restarted the instance and its started again fine.

the question is, how can i know what happened? is there some sort of a log, or a way to know what happened exactly? since i don't want this issue to reappear in the future

Comment: Try asking ec2 technical support. For future you might want to use monitoring tool.

Comment: the problem, there is no logging from AWS itself for the ec2 instances, i use the AWS management console for monitoring

Comment: Check to see if the Public IP address has changed. If you still have problems shutdown the instance and then start (don't use restart). Then note the new Public IP address. If you need permanent access via SSH to your instance, assign an EIP to the instance.

Comment: i already restarted the instance and its working fine now, and yes the public IP changes every time you restart the EC2 instance, its working now, but i need to know what caused the problem in the first place so i can avoid it in future